# Mobile Safari-style back button for UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, uibarbuttonitem

I haven't been able to find any sort UIBarButtonSystemItem representing tha "Back" button in Mobile Safari. I want my UIWebView's controls to look just like the ones in Mobile Safari so it makes sense. Would the best solution be to just screenshot UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay (same image as the Forward button) and flip it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the right move is to try and find the raw icon somewhere (try Terminal, and find in your /Developer directory).

It's possible that

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.sdk/Applications/WebSheet.app/ArrowBack.png
```

is the right file.

Just taking a screenshot isn't going to work, as the toolbar icons are based on alpha levels rather than colours. If you grab a screenshot and flip it, you'll just end up with a solid square for your button.

Comment: XCode 4.3.1 is now distributed as a stand alone app store app. The relevant folder is now /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/Applications/WebSheet.app, but unfortunately it no longer contains the ArrowBack.png file :(

Comment: I have just found some arrows under /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/Applications/MobileSafari.app/FindOnPagePreviousResult.png

Answer (score 23):

I just made them for myself, basically they are exact copies (don't count the pixels though). You may use them in any way you like, commercially or not. Just don't try to sell them please.

[File removed, iOS 7 introduced a whole new look for those buttons.]

Comment: Thanks, they were helpful.  But how much would someone really pay for two black triangles?

Comment: I recently revamped my website and it looks like I ditched them, since iOS 7 introduced a new look.

Comment: @ff10 please can you give me your webview icons? 
i didn't find the attachment that you've uploaded

Answer (score 8):

Unicode is your friend here.

Create a UIBarButtonItem (in Interface Builder or in code) and set it to "Custom" where you can enter text for the button.

Now use these Unicode characters to simulate the back & forward buttons:

◄ and ►

I use it in my apps and it looks great.

Comment: This is a great idea, however in my case the triangles are squashed. Any idea how to fix it? [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/49yfA.png)

Comment: Try using a different font, or using a different Triangle Character (see here: http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/geometric_shapes.html)

Comment: I tried this but it put a border around the buttons. @PaulWieland how did you do it without the borders? Could you guys share the code? THanks!

Comment: @MattDiPasquale I believe there is an option in interface builder to turn the border off

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem but have found a very nice solution:

http://outerlevel.com/blog/2008/12/26/code-example-drawing-the-iphone-back-button/

But you have to change some values

as the following:

```
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 8.0f, 12.0f);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 24.0f, 3.0f);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 24.0f, 21.0f);
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

only a little tweak from me because the back button was not aligned to the forward button, back button was 1px too high. btw should I make this to community Wiki ? im new here ...

Comment: hail Unicode :) the solution above with the unicode chars is brilliant and very simple!

Answer (score 2):

If I just use unicode for left-pointing triangle @"\U000025C0", it uses Apple Color Emoji.
To use simple symbol without color, use unicode variation selector for text style emoji("\U0000FE0E").

So, string for the left-pointing triangle is @"\U000025C0\U0000FE0E".

I think this is the matter only on iPhone Simulator(on Mountain Lion supporting unicode 6.1), and does not cause problem on actual device, yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how iPhone apps are packaged, but if you can open the .app folder and poke around, you should be able to find the actual image file in there in the resources folder...